# UglifyJS throws unexpected token: keyword (const) with node_modules

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, babeljs, uglifyjs2

A small project I started make use a node module (installed via **npm**) that declares `const` variables. Running and testing this project is well, but browserify fails when UglifyJS is executed.

> Unexpected token: keyword (const)

Here is a generic Gulp file that I have successfully been using for a few other past projects without this issue (i.e. without that particular node module).

#### gulpfile.js

```js
'use strict';

const browserify = require('browserify');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
const derequire = require('gulp-derequire');
const buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const gutil = require('gulp-util');
const path = require('path');
const pkg = require('./package');
const upperCamelCase = require('uppercamelcase');

const SRC_PATH = path.dirname(pkg.main);
const DIST_PATH = path.dirname(pkg.browser);

const INPUT_FILE = path.basename(pkg.main);
const OUTPUT_FILE = path.basename(pkg.browser);

const MODULE_NAME = upperCamelCase(pkg.name);


gulp.task('default', () => {
  // set up the browserify instance on a task basis
  var b = browserify({
    entries: INPUT_FILE,
    basedir: SRC_PATH,
    transform: ['babelify'],
    standalone: MODULE_NAME,
    debug: true
  });

  return b.bundle()
    .pipe(source(OUTPUT_FILE))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(derequire())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(DIST_PATH))
  ;
});
```

I have tried fixing this by replace all `const` to `var` in that npm-installed module, and everything is fine. So I do not understand the failure.

What's wrong with `const`? Unless someone uses IE10, *all* major browsers support this syntax.

Is there a way to fix this without requiring a change to that node module?

### Update

I have temporarily (or permanently) replaced UglifyJS with [Butternut](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/butternut) and seem to work.

Comment: Isn't it a problem with the node version? Don't you need like node 8+ to have `const` available? (not sure when it was actually introduced)

Comment: I have been using `const` since v4. And I am currently using 8.9.1 LTS.

Comment: Ok that's strange then. What's the error message you are seeing?

Comment: @this.lau_ the same error message as in the title, but I added it in the question as well for clarity.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be about the 'const'. It could be one of the modules that you're requiring.

Comment: @Adrián I thought that as well, but I manually edited the file under `node_modules` and replaced all `const` to `var` and UglifyJS didn't complain whatsoever. Then I *added* a `const T = 'foo';` and UglifyJS complained again.

Comment: Maybe you need some other helper module, I remember this same thing happened to me on a new project. I'm not sure how I fixed it but I have this modules as well:

---------------------------------------------
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "1.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.0",

Comment: What I mean is you could try to uninstall that UglifyJS version and install the one I installed (if not the same). It should tell you about dependencies if any required.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

As [ChrisR mentionned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47440295/2294168), UglifyJS does not support ES6 at all.

You need to use [terser-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin) for ES6 (webpack@5 will use this plugin for uglification)

```
npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then define in your `plugins` array

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')

  new TerserPlugin({
    parallel: true,
    terserOptions: {
      ecma: 6,
    },
  }),
```

[Source](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/362#issuecomment-425849160)

Comment: Maybe you should suggest `npm install --save-dev terser-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer because it reminded me about the `terser` lib that `terser-webpack-plugin` uses underneath. Note for others: `terser` can be used standalone as cli just as `uglify-js` was (i.e. webpack is not a requirement) which was exactly what I needed.

Comment: but we need to use webpack to use this solution?

Comment: @enrique depends what you want to do, to build an website that matches real business needs you should definitely give a try to webpack. We had that issue on the webpack community so my answer is well rated but technically you don't need webpack to build ES6 code

Comment: Terser was cherry-picked to webpack@4 in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/8392

Comment: uglifyjs.terser Ubuntu package worked for me.

Answer (score 42):

UglifyJS does not support es6. `const` is an es6 declaration, so it throws an error.

What is weird is that the package you use does not transpile its files to es5 to be used anywhere.

If you want to still use UglifyJS (to re-use the configuration for example) use the ES6+ compatible version, [uglify-es](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/tree/harmony). (**Warning**: `uglify-es` is [now abandoned](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/releases/tag/v2.0.0).)

And as [Ser mentionned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53336031/8575499), you should now use `terser-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: You can also replace `gulp-uglify`by `gulp-uglify-es`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify-es

Comment: `UglifyJS does not support es6 `. Thank you! I could not find that piece of info anywhere.

Comment: use `gulp-terser` if migrating to webpack is out of your budget.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and the gulp plugin **gulp-uglify-es** resolved the problem.

I think it's the simpliest decision.

Just install:

```
npm i gulp-uglify-es --save-dev
```

after that in your code change only this line

```
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
```

to this:

```
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
```

N.B. property **.default** is crucial otherwise  you'll have an error that uglify is not a function.

As mentioned above and as being part of ES6 **const** operator can only be processed by more modern es6 gulp plugin "gulp-uglify-es"

The rest of your code no need to be changed.

Best regards!

Comment: tested and working with "node : v12.14", "gulp cli v2.2.1", "gulp local v4.0.2".

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue with a Gulp project I refactored and for some reason I was having trouble with the official Terser Gulp plugin. [This one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-terser) (gulp-terser) worked with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Solved an upgrade problem that was returning the same by uninstalling and reinstalling UglifyJS, and ensuring node_modules were aligned.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev
npm i
```

(Updated for suggested improvements)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, I'm confused about using `npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev` before removing the `node_modules` directory. Why don't you start with `rm -rf node_modules`, then `npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev
` and finally `npm i`?

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced `UglifyJS` with `YUI Compressor JS` inside the GUI of PHPStorm.. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think that this approach is good, but in my case I needed to do this once and forget about that, so I just went to [babel's website](https://babeljs.io/en/repl) , transpile es6 to es5 online and replaced the output!

Answer (score -1):

Use uglify-es-webpack-plugin is better

```
    const UglifyEsPlugin = require('uglify-es-webpack-plugin')



    module.exports = {
    plugins: [
            new UglifyEsPlugin({
                compress:{
                    drop_console: true
                }
            }),
    ] 
    }
```

Comment: This is an opinion, please elaborate on why it is better.